# Testing Integration Procedure with Session cache

Tags: vlocity, integration-procedure, session-cache

I have a unit test where I am mocking an Integration Procedure that invokes an HTTP callout.

```
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
// ...
IntegrationProcedureServiceTest.setMockHttpResponse(res)
```

This requires `@isTest(seeAllData=true` for the test to see the IP! However when I attempt to invoke the IP, I get:

`Session cache is only supported in Data Silo test`

So I'm thinking I cannot actually test IPs when using Session Cache?

[Related Apex testing of Integration procedure doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_integration_procedure_unit_testing_from_apex.htm&type=5)

Comment: What does _invoke the IP_ mean

Comment: @identigral integration procedure.  It's an OmniScript/vlocity feature that connects the UI script with Apex.

Comment: the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_integration_procedure_unit_testing_from_apex.htm&type=5) doesn't say anything about session cache. Can you refactor your session cache code into a service class and then dependency inject a mock service class before executing the test?

Comment: @cropredy We have session cache code similar to what your describing, when I attempt to invoke that, I get an exception when testing to see if the cache is populated before populating it. `chache.Org.OrgCacheException`

Comment: but if the cache logic is all in a service class, and you create a mock of that class in unit test , and inject mock in the unit test, then while running the unit test, the mock class can just return true/false depending on use case